# cygwin warning: COMDAT symbol does not match section name

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I am using g++ (5.4.0) on cygwin, to compile and link some cpp files. Compilation goes through fine, but during linking I get many errors like:

```
lib.a: warning: COMDAT symbol '.pdata$_ZnwmPv' does not match section name '.pdata'
lib.a: warning: COMDAT symbol '.xdata$_ZnwmPv' does not match section name '.xdata'
```

I am not able to figure out what this message means, nor how to fix the problem. I tried a google search, and got this link: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15041
It seems to indicate that the problem is fixed and checked in, way back in 2013.

So does my error message mean that this fix is not available in the gcc of cygwin? Or is there something else that I need to do to fix/bypass this problem?

Also, is there any way I can get more details on what exactly is the mismatch? That may indicate what I need to fix in my code.

**Some more details** : The warning occurs only in cygwin, and not in ubuntu, so I have also added the cygwin tag to this question and also mentioned cygwin in the question. And it happens only when I add the following code to my classes. If the **addObject2** method is deleted, and the private member **_obj2Array** is made public and its code is moved to the application, then the warning goes away.

myObject1.h:

```
class myObject1: public myParent {
    ... // constructors, etc
    vector<myObject2*> _obj2Array;
    public:
    void addObject2(myObject2* obj2);
}
```

myObject1.cpp:

```
void myObject1::addObject2(myObject2* obj2) {
   _obj2Array.push_back(obj2);
}
```